# Browser is sending cookie header in API request call , How to prevent this behavior?

Tags: cookies, request, frontend

While making API request browser is sending all cookies in cookie header in all API calls.

I want to avoid this browser behaviour and I tried setting up this header via code but it's overwritten by browser. Any lead on this topic will be appreciated .